# appropriate action for low quality questions

Tags: discussion

Whats an appropriate flag for this type of unconstructive question?

> I will love to have in D7 the NavBar Menu whenever I'm on my phone but
>   whenever I'm at my desktop I will love to have Admin Menu. The ability
>   of having both menu is possible ?
>
> Have anyone done this before ?

I flagged it as low quality -- I could see it as Closable too. I'm also asumming English is not the authors 1st language. Usually trying to engage the author rarely results in a better question...

Thanks!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216110/225745 please. No point in repeating ;)

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think this deserves a VLQ flag.

It could possibly be closed for more info to specify which admin menu (toolbar vs admin_menu), or even just a comment asking for more info.

It could also be edited into a better question w/o changing the meaning and intent of the question.

Since both of those are valid options and can be done by anyone (with appropriate privileges), a flag isn't needed.

Comment: I guess i'm of the mindset only the author can re-word this into a better question if he could be more specific. In general answers to both his questions would be `yes, and yes`. But a general answer doesn't help his current general question. Without the author taking _some_ effort choose an approach to the problem or do some initial research -- I find his initial inquiry shallow.

Comment: If OP is not specific enough, then action should be close -> too broad, or close -> unclear, not VLQ flag.